# I am able to click on filter option on website,my question is " filter option was opened by using xpath and at a time filter option will be closed"

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I am able to click on filter option on website,my question is " filter option was opened by using xpath and at a time filter option will be closed"

Code trials:

```
WebElement element= driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[contains(@class,'slds-button slds-button--icon-border-filled action-control__button action-control--square')]"));
JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element);
```

Comment: Hi Divya, welcome to StackOverflow!
Your question is not clear and your code is not formatted, so is difficult to understand, please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and reformulate it with a good title, more context and formatted code, that will help people help you better!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To `click()` on the element you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48989049/selenium-how-selenium-identifies-elements-visible-or-not-is-is-possible-that-i/48990165#48990165) for the `elementToBeClickable()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- `cssSelector`:

  ```
  ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].click();", new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("button.slds-button.slds-button--icon-border-filled.action-control__button.action-control--square"))));
  ```
- `xpath`:

  ```
  ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].click();", new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//button[@class='slds-button slds-button--icon-border-filled action-control__button action-control--square']"))));
  ```